# Arduino nano ATmega328p with CH341 won't upload

Tags: arduino-nano, uploading

When I try to upload a sketch to an Arduino Nano, it stays stuck on uploading, and after a time it shows the following error code:

- stk500_getsync() attempt 1 of 10: not in sync: resp=0xc2
  stk500_getsync() attempt 2 of 10: not in sync: resp=0xc2
  stk500_getsync() attempt 3 of 10: not in sync: resp=0xc2
  stk500_getsync() attempt 4 of 10: not in sync: resp=0xc2
  stk500_getsync() attempt 5 of 10: not in sync: resp=0xc2
  stk500_getsync() attempt 6 of 10: not in sync: resp=0xc2
  stk500_getsync() attempt 7 of 10: not in sync: resp=0xc2
  stk500_getsync() attempt 8 of 10: not in sync: resp=0xc2
  stk500_getsync() attempt 9 of 10: not in sync: resp=0xc2
  stk500_getsync() attempt 10 of 10: not in sync: resp=0xc2

Sometimes the `resp=0xc2` variable changes to another hex code.

The weird thing here is that before this happened everything worked fine. I could upload and the serial communication was fine. But after trying to upload the same sketch with a different variable, this started to happen.

Windows recognizes the COM port, in Arduino the COM port is selected. Sometimes, without doing anything, the Arduino works fine again, I can see the serial communication fine, but after some time the serial communication stops sending and again I can't upload the sketch.

I have 2 Arduino Nanos. Both of them start presenting the same problem. But the other one has the Power, RX, and TX led always on and this one never worked again, like the other one that sometimes can upload the sketch and see the serial communication that the last sketch was sending. I have an Arduino Mega, this one has the ATmega16U2 to communicate to USB and this one works fine. And I also have a NodeMCU Lua, with CH341. But this one works just fine.

Comment: Do you have an oscilloscope? If so, check on the RX and TX pins if, when writing something in a serial terminal, a signal passes through the USB/UART bridge. If it does, the problem is the microcontroller (maybe flash the bootloader again). If it doesn't, the CH341 is broken. Also check the +5V voltage...

Comment: I don't have an oscilloscope :(. I manage to upload the Blink program and at first time it was blinking at the rate of 1 second, but after some time the blink start going wild and start blinking really fast. About the serial communication, I put RST to ground, and connect RX to TX and I opened the serial monitor and I start sending words and both RX and TX light up every time i hit enter. But nothing show in terminal. I already flash the bootloader again in both and still the same. In the one that the TX and RX are always on, it didnt let me flash the bootloader.

Comment: The suggestion by John Allen is exactly what it took to get my 1.8.5 IDE to upload successfully to my Nano boards. Happy Day!!
Just a note - the 'ATMega328P (Old bootloader)' option does not seem to be available in IDE 1.8.5 on my old WinXP machine.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using a fairly recent version of the Arduino IDE, try using the old bootloader for the 328P.
Go to Tools --> Processor:"ATmega329P" --> ATmega328P(Old Bootloader)

Answer (score 0):

Open your device manager in computer if ot would show your arduino nano as USB 2.0 then you need to install CH340G DRIVERS from Google install it and then again connect it to the computer your problem would be solved but remember to remove TX and RX pins before uploading code...